# Perform a simple HTTP request using C++ / Boost via a proxy?

Tags: c++, http, boost, proxy, request

I'm quite a newbie with Boost, and my only experience of surfing though a proxy using a library is using .NET (that is really convenient for that purpose). I'm now trying to perform a simple HTTP request through a HTTP proxy.

Is there a tidy way to do it using boost directly?

My proxy use a NTLM authentification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Boost provides neither an HTTP client nor a way to interface with proxies. You would necessarily have to implement those features yourself.

To be clear, yes, it is possible to implement an HTTP client using Boost.Asio. But implementing a client that can reliably talk through a proxy is significantly more complex, and Asio does not provide any support for that beyond the low-level socket itself. It certainly does not include the framework for performing NTLM authentication, which may prove difficult to get right.

More complex libraries like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) provide that support.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp

Comment: To whoever downvoted: Code example != API-provided support. Boost::ASIO makes *implementing* an HTTP client simple, but it does not provide a full HTTP client, less one with support for proxies, as the question specifically requests. Furthermore, my answer was posted when 1.40 was the latest stable.

Comment: @anno: providing a socket is not the same as priding an HTTP request. The socket makes it simple(r) to make the HTTP request but you still need to understand the HTTP protocol to use the socket. Could they just not have a simple utility class that wraps the functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, learning HTTP requests is as easy as learning a new API for making requests (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message).

Comment: @anno - there is more to sending a HTTP request than just headers etc. Discovering proxies, running PACs and then authenticating to the proxies is a huge challenge. A trivial implementation using asio to stuff a few headers and a payload will not work in most corporate environmments.