# How i can send an HttpRequest from C++

Tags: c++, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm using DataServices and OData protocol. I need to generate HTTP Get, Post, Delete, and Update from a C++ application.  How I can do this?  What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 2):

Try [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). check out this SO post.  [Perform a simple HTTP request using C++ / Boost via a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430495/perform-a-simple-http-request-using-c-boost-via-a-proxy)

Answer (score 2):

The [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) library is another alternative to [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/asio/index.html). There's an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp) of a simple HTTP client (with a GET request).

Answer (score 1):

You can use MS stuff: [Wininet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this old post.

[Beast](http://vinniefalco.github.io/) is a cross-platform, header-only, modern C++11 library built on [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) that provides implementations of the HTTP and WebSocket protocols.
The project is under evaluation to be included in Boost, so it may be worth looking at it.