# Best way of implementing a server in C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, http, rest

I want to implement a nonblocking HTTP/REST server that will support multiple clients at the same time and I was wondering if there is any API that does this very well or what is the best way of implementing this server some opinions about threading and using the basic socket, bind and listen functions or other better software. 
I have used in the past bind listen and the other basic C stuff but I want to know if other better options exists. An easy to use and complete api for implementing a http server in C/C++

Answer (score 1):

Libmicrohttpd. It is simple and seems to be a great option.
http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/

Comment: I can see there are a lot of example of a http server for boost:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html
Do you think that boost libmicrohttpd is a better option that boost ? and if yes why ?

Comment: Im sorry, not familiar with boost.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has [some great asynchronous IO support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html). One of the tutorials is a TCP server.

Comment: I was thinking of Boost.thread and Boost.asio but is there any http support in boost? Or what can I use to deal with http requests?

Comment: Apparently not, but the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430495/perform-a-simple-http-request-using-c-boost-via-a-proxy) mentions [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) as a possibility ... Sorry, I just don't know too much about implementations of a full HTTP client

Comment: This seems to be a great option http://cpp-netlib.org/#